# Invariant Violation when calling constructor on React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting started with React and I was was trying to define a new component that has a constructor class. My more intricate element wasn't working, so I tried the example that I saw from the docs. Here is my JS file

```
let React = require('react');

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Counter.propTypes = { initialCount: React.PropTypes.number };
Counter.defaultProps = { initialCount: 0 };

React.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Taken straight from React's docs. However when I load the page I get the error `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define 'constructor' on your component more than once. This conflict may be due to a mixin.` in the console.

Now I'm using Material UI and React-Router in my overall app, and are loaded in my Vendor file, but I haven't required them at all in this file. Any thoughts as to what this could be?

Comment: It seems to work just fine in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waQbRz

Comment: Code is working for me as well - I think your issue may be elsewhere. One thing I would add - instead of binding this onClick - you can also handle the this binding in the constructor - ie: this.tick = this.tick.bind(this) (the reason for this is that using ES6 removes the autobinding handled by React (at least until decorators make things nicer in es7)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use constructor but the native getInitialeState function. You don't need the super function I'm not sure using ES6 here is that useful and clear.

Also always use setState and never state = //soemthing/ this is a really bad practice
From the documentation "NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable."

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

I've read this blog article advising you to do things like state=//stuf 
http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes
and maybe you've been inspired  by it but, speaking for myself, I would not follow advises from a guy writing to do the contrary of what's advised in the documentation. (**NEVER mutate...**).

I hope it helps.

Comment: The poster is doing exactly what the React docs say to do: "The API is similar to React.createClass with the exception of getInitialState. Instead of providing a separate getInitialState method, you set up your own state property in the constructor." http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Comment: As mentioned by Kyle - this is exactly the way to use ES6 classes with React according to React (notice using this.state in the constructor now as opposed to using getInitialState)- https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Kyle and Gabdallah for testing and confirming that it works. It turns out that it was Material UI that was messing with the code (which, coincidentally, I seriously do not recommend - much too rigid for my tastes).

And to reiterate, this example was taken straight from the React docs and is the recommended way for using ES6. Hope this helps someone in the future!